# Kusto query to sort dynamically (based of count of a field)

Tags: sql, azure, group-by, sql-order-by, azure-data-explorer

Lets say I have a table structure and data like -

```
Id  ErrorType Desc
=== ========= ====
1   DOWN      Item 1 desc
2   DOWN      Item 2 desc
3   SLOW      Item 3 desc
4   DOWN      Item 4 desc
5   PERF      Item 5 desc
6   SLOW      Item 6 desc
```

What kusto query should I use to sort the above data by ErrorType values count. Meaning - Show all DOWN errors (as they are 3 in count), followed by SLOW errors (2 in count) and PERF error. The rearranged data should look like -

```
Id  ErrorType Desc
=== ========= ====
1   DOWN      Item 1 desc
2   DOWN      Item 2 desc
4   DOWN      Item 4 desc
3   SLOW      Item 3 desc
6   SLOW      Item 6 desc
5   PERF      Item 5 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the [top-nested operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/topnestedoperator)